# Module not found even though in sys.path, only one conda env

Tags: python, github, conda, package.json

A module is not found when trying to import it. I've searched for a similar question but could not find the same issue, usually the problem was within different conda environments.

I have a fully updated anaconda installed with python 3.8 and only that version and i have no other environments. *conda env list* only returns the base environment.

I used conda to install git and pip and installed a package from github with that pip.
When using *conda list* it is listed. Trying *conda remove --package-name* results in conda not finding the package.

When using *pip uninstall package-name* the package is found and can be deinstalled.

When using *sys.path* the python3.8/site-packages folder is shown where i can also find that package folder, but the module is not found.
When directly appending the package-folder with *sys.path.append(folder-path)*, the module is still not found.

Please help me out with that as i would really like to confidently import packages from the gitHub community without worrying :(

Comment: Can you state the package? Some of the trivial things that come to mind are 1) the package name and module name may not be identical; 2) the GitHub "package" isn't actually a package, but just some scripts someone loosely calls a package.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay! Its pltconverter from https://github.com/thomashirtz/plt-converter   he even gave an example where he is importing it.

Comment: So, you used the command `pip install git+https://github.com/thomashirtz/plt-converter#egg=pltconverter`?

Comment: @merv i copied it yes. I also deinstalled git and reinstalled it with conda too make sure it is executed under conda.